# Concurrent Quick sort using python. Need to use XML file as input

Tags: xml, python-3.x, input

I am running a concurrent quick sort program in python but I have provided static input to the code. I want to use xml file as input to the code. I want to pass numbers in xml file.
Below is the code I have. Please help!

```
from threading import Thread
import threading

import time
import _thread
import xml
data = []
def qsort(sets,left,right):

print("thread {0} is sorting {1}".format(threading.current_thread(), sets[left:right]))

i = left
j = right
pivot = sets[(left + right)//2]
temp = 0
while(i <= j):
     while(pivot > sets[i]):
         i = i+1
     while(pivot < sets[j]):
         j = j-1
     if(i <= j):
         temp = sets[i]
         sets[i] = sets[j]
         sets[j] = temp
         i = i + 1
         j = j - 1

lthread = None
rthread = None

if (left < j):
    lthread = Thread(target = lambda: qsort(sets,left,j))
    lthread.start()

if (i < right):
    rthread = Thread(target=lambda: qsort(sets,i,right))
    rthread.start()

if lthread is not None: lthread.join()
if rthread is not None: rthread.join()
return sets


'''testing below'''
ls = [1,3,6,9,1,2,3,8,6]
res = qsort(ls, 0, len(ls) - 1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
***from xml.dom import minidom***
import time
import _thread
import xml
data = []
***doc=minidom.parse("filenam.xml")***
***items=doc.getElementsByTagName("element")***
***for i in items:***
      ***data.append(int(i.attributes['val'].value.encode("utf-8")))***
def qsort(sets,left,right):

print("thread {0} is sorting {1}".format(threading.current_thread(), sets[left:right]))

i = left
j = right
pivot = sets[(left + right)//2]
temp = 0
while(i <= j):
     while(pivot > sets[i]):
         i = i+1
     while(pivot < sets[j]):
         j = j-1
     if(i <= j):
         temp = sets[i]
         sets[i] = sets[j]
         sets[j] = temp
         i = i + 1
         j = j - 1

lthread = None
rthread = None

if (left < j):
    lthread = Thread(target = lambda: qsort(sets,left,j))
    lthread.start()

if (i < right):
    rthread = Thread(target=lambda: qsort(sets,i,right))
    rthread.start()

if lthread is not None: lthread.join()
if rthread is not None: rthread.join()
return sets



//////////////////////////////////////////
for this create an xml file name "filename.xml "
content of xml file :



<input>
        <element no='34'></element>
        <element no='3'></element>
            <element no='4'></element>

</input>



try this i hope it helps
```